# Animating a logo flying from the corner to the center of screen

Tags: javascript, user-interface, animation

My app has a static logo in the top-left of the screen, and there are a few moments when I have an animated version of that logo in the center of the screen for about two seconds. I was thinking it would be an interesting effect if I could animate the logo moving from the corner to the center and then becoming the animated version, instead of having two instances of it.

This is what it looks like.

[image]

Any thoughts how I could approach a problem like that? I was thinking of using an overlay and animating the entire screen, but that wouldn't be ideal both since the screen can and probably will change, and also because I couldn't get that to look right on multiple size screens.

Is there a more intuitive way to do something like that?

Comment: Have you tried `CSS keyframes`

Comment: I have not, but I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you can use a transform for both of them. A slide transform for the small one and a fade transform for the large one.
The smaller logo could slide and enlarge, and at the timestamp it hits the center, the larger icon could "fade-in" instantly.
You'd be setting the image width/height and the offsets to percentages.

I'm not the best at execution, but this is how I would approach it.

Edit: Then to have the small logo in the corner, you could have it fade back in as the animated logo finishes.